# For local SEO, should all target queries include our location?

Tags: seo, google-search, local-seo

It's a local restaurant and I need it to narrow down to city-only search results.

So instead of targeting keywords like "best Asian restaurants" Do I need to use keyword + target city like "best asian restaurants in **wellington**" like this every time?

Comment: "Do I need to use keyword + target city like "best asian restaurants in wellington" like this every time?" - Are you speaking about keywords that you use in your content? You sound like adding target keywords in an ad campaign... Please can you add clarity?

Answer (score 2):

The question is what audience you'll target?

As you'll try to advertise a restaurant, that is bounded to one particular place in the world, so of course, geographical targeting is very important for you.

You haven't mentioned what exactly and where you try to do SEO efforts. But check out
Google My Business (Formerly "Google Places for Business") https://www.google.com/business/

This is how you can get your Restaurant on Google maps (Apple Maps in the USA as important well). And it should be no surprise, that for restaurants people do look up google maps via their phones most of the time... Hope this helps for the start.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the user device and connection type for local search, the minimum distance will be 9 km.

You do not need to include the name of the city in the title or description if you have indicated it in the profile or contact section of the site.

> [Distance](https://support.google.com/business/answer/7091) considers how far each potential search result is from the
> location term used in a search. If a user doesn't specify a location
> in their search, we’ll calculate distance based on what we do know
> about their location.